# Exception in django db close_connection

Tags: python, django

In a program which make a lot of queries to a MySQL database, i get sometimes some **OperationalError** as specified in the [pep249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/). It always happen when the database is heavy loaded and the error is a [MySQL server has gone away](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html).

The workaround we are using is to retry the query after N seconds until it works. It looks like

```
while True:
    try:
        # do stuff...
        break
    except OperationalError as e:
        db.close_connection() # As specified in http://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2012/01/06/django-reset-database-connection.html
```

In some rare cases, i observe that the "db.close_connection()" instruction also fails. It forces me to use the same workaround for that instruction (eg retry until it works). Here is the error i get:

```
  File "/home/prod/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/dwloader/loaders/DjangoLoader.py", line 30, in wrapper
    db.close_connection()
  File "/home/prod/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 76, in close_connection
    transaction.abort(conn)
  File "/home/prod/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 58, in abort
    get_connection(using).abort()
  File "/home/prod/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 42, in get_connection
    return connections[using]
  File "/home/prod/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 196, in __getitem__
    self.ensure_defaults(alias)
  File "/home/prod/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 174, in ensure_defaults
    conn.setdefault('ATOMIC_REQUESTS', False)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setdefault'
```

I have several questions here:

1. Under which circumstances this exception happens?
2. Is it normal that this instruction can raise an exception?
3. Is it the right way to handle this exception?

I use **Django 1.6**.

Comment: Are you using several threads ? It looks like you are trying to close a connection that has already been destroyed.

Comment: Yes i am, looks like close_connection is not thread safe